# What can I do about excessive lime flavor in a pork roast?

Tags: flavor, pork, lime

I marinated a pork roast in lime, garlic, oregano and a little olive oil.  The flavor of lime is over-bearing.  Is there anything I can do to counter the lime taste?

Comment: You've heard of margarita chicken? Add salt around the edges and call it "Margarita Pork"?

Answer (score 3):

Since I assume it is too late to do anything to take the lime away, undermine excess flavor of lime with roasted peppers. They will bear a pleasant complement to the tartness while adding rich, smoky notes. Hotter peppers will further distract from the excess lime. A sweet corn salsa would also add sweetness to anchor the lime.

Comment: Yes, too late -- it is fully cooked now.  I had already thought of corn as a side dish, will just turn it into a salsa and will roast some peppers as well.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Salt balances with sour flavors really well.  There's still an upper limit on how much salt or lime can be considered enjoyable by most people.  I'd start with salt, ideally in a marinade, to take advantage of the acidity unless it's already pretty salty.

If that approach is taken to its limit and it's still too sour, the only route I see is dilution--reduce the amount of pork going into anyone's mouth...shredded pork in soft tacos or wraps comes to mind.  Thin slices would also work in a sandwich.